# preg_match a hyperlink

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I looked everywhere for an answer, but it seems I cannot get my head around `preg_match` functionality. I want to `preg_match` the link below where only the numbers part (the ID) is dynamic.

**Link:**

```
http://video.cnbc.com/gallery/?video=3000024508
```

**Here goes what I have come up until now:**

```
preg_match( '/^http://video.cnbc.com/gallery/?video=([0-9_-]/', $content )
```

But it won't work.

Comment: . and ? are special characters in regular expressions, and you never closed the parenthesis after [0-9_-].

Comment: http://www.quanetic.com/Regex is a great site to experiment with regular expressions on.

Comment: @ceejayoz The ? is part of the URL I'm trying to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 preg_match('#^http://video\.cnbc\.com/gallery/\?video=([0-9_-]+)$#', $content);
```

[RegExr Demo](http://regexr.com?2u496)

Besides problems that others mentioned (escaping the `?` and `.` and using `#` instead of `/`) you are also missing a `+` from after the number group (`[0-9_-]`), which means that group can be repeated.

If you need to check if a string *includes* this kind of link or not, remove `^` and `$`:

`preg_match('#http://video\.cnbc\.com/gallery/\?video=([0-9_-]+)#', $content);`

Comment: This is not matching either. Where can be the problem?

Comment: I just tested it and it returns `1` for `$content="http://video.cnbc.com/gallery/?video=3000024508";`. What's the problem you found?

Comment: It returns 0 here. I've got that link in the middle of some content.

Comment: @Banago Then you need to remove `^` and `$`. Those mark the beginning and end of the subject.

Comment: Returned one - thanks! Will update you with the results later

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're missing a close paren after [0-9_-] and you didn't escape properly. Use # instead of / and you'll get this:

```
preg_match( '#^http://video\.cnbc\.com/gallery/\?video=([0-9_-]+)#', $content )
```

Comment: This will not match the given link.

Comment: Well, at one point, I had a slip-up in there, an extra / instead of a +. but JavaScript says that this is true: /http:\/\/video\.cnbc\.com\/gallery\/\?video=([0-9_-]+)/.test("http://video.cnbc.com/gallery/?video=3000024508"). If you use # as a delimiter, you can skip the extra escapes of the other /'s

Comment: php -r "echo preg_match( '#^http://video\.cnbc\.com/gallery/\?video=([0-9_-]+)#', 'http://video.cnbc.com/gallery/?video=3000024508');" => 1. Seems to match it to me. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't escape it properly:

```
preg_match( '/^http:\/\/video.cnbc.com\/gallery\/\?video=([0-9_-])/', $content)
```

Here are the problem characters:

- `/` means start and end of regex, you were ending it after `http:`
- `?` means the previous character is optional.

You also forgot a closing parenthesis.

Comment: This will not match the given link.